# How to create a cached NSNumberFormatter in Swift 3?

Tags: caching, swift3, string-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I am wondering how to create a cached NSNumberFormatter (NumberFormatter) in Swift 3?

This is what I found via searching Gists;

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    private static var cache:[String:NumberFormatter] = [:]

    static func numberFormatterForKey(key:String, initialize:((NumberFormatter)->())? = nil) -> NumberFormatter {
        if let formatter = NumberFormatter.cache[key] {
            return formatter
        } else {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            NumberFormatter.cache[key] = formatter
            initialize?(formatter)
            return formatter
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to use it; or if there is a better solution.

Thus, How to create a cached NSNumberFormatter in Swift 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since resolved the issue;

I create my cached nsnumberformatter like this;

```
struct ObjectCache {
    static let currencyRateFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        var numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        numberFormatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = false
        return numberFormatter
    }()
}
```

Then use it like this;

```
self.myCashLbl.text = ObjectCache.currencyRateFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(integerLiteral: player.cash))
```

Thanks.